# Double neutral wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]I'm replacing an outlet and came across this wiring, which I had not seen so far in any other outlet in my house. It's not pigtailed, both neutral are just shoved into the same terminal. Should I mimic this in my replacement or do something different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like they shoved 2 ends under the screw - that would be very shoddy indeed.  It looks like they stripped insulation off about 1" of the wire mid-run, and looped it around the screw.  That's legit.

If you need to cut that for some reason, either pigtail or cut it dead in the middle and get a "screw-and-clamp" type recep, which allows 2 wires per screw. Easy peasy.

Comment: ...How engineers (or fussy technicians) reduce the resistance of the connection to the next device ever-so-slightly by cutting only the insulation, so the conductor is unbroken. I resemble this remark when it makes sense. Few electricians will bother, in my limited experience.